# Typeerror when using zip

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to add specific rows from several xlsx files to lists with my python script. The rows I am trying to add are the rows where cell values of column number 4 (E column) minus cell values of column number 1 (B column) are not equal to 0. My xlsx files look like this:

```
   A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
1 A10   2        A10   2             AB
2 A105  1        A105  2             AB
```

So for the following code I want the second row to be added to the open list numbers, because the sum of 2-1 is not 0. Then I want to sort them by adding them to column lists, and then put them into a new list, mainlist, where everything is sorted. Here is my code:

```
import logging
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import glob
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

numbers = []
rapp = r"C:\Myfolder"
files = glob.glob(rapp)
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    numbers = df.iloc[:, 4], df.iloc[:,1][df.iloc[:, 4] - df.iloc[:,1] != 0].tolist()
excel_input = load_workbook(excelfile)
ws = excel_input.active
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)
else:
    pass

col1 = []
col2 = []
col4 = []
col5 = []
col7 = []
col8 = []

mainlist = []
try:
    for row in numbers:
        col1.append(ws.cell(row=row, column=1).value)
        col2.append(ws.cell(row=row, column=2).value)
        col4.append(ws.cell(row=row, column=4).value)
        col5.append(ws.cell(row=row, column=5).value)
        col7.append(ws.cell(row=row, column=7).value)
        col8.append(ws.cell(row=row, column=8).value)
except AttributeError:
    logging.error('Something is wrong')
finally:
    for col1, col2, col4, col5, col7, col8 in zip: #Error
        mainlist.append(col1, col2, col4, col5, col7, col8)
return mainlist
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback:
    for col1, col2, col4, col5, col7, col8 in zip 
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable.
```

This is giving me errors. 
I know there are some mistakes here, and I am sorry, but this was the best that I could come up with to solve my task. Can anyone help me on my way? I would be very greatful! I am new to python. Working in Python 3.4.1.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the specific errors you are encountering. Please also review the help page on [minimum, complete, verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The error is already written there, but I have added a comment to where it is at in the script.

Comment: How is everything sorted, I do not understand this part... "Then I want to sort them by adding them to column lists, and then put them into a new list, mainlist, where everything is sorted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're issue is your use of `zip`, which is a variable you never define.  However, because `zip()` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) which returns a [`zip-class` object](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8dQwVYh2lDHSMc4livHCMQx0THVMYvlqgKyqzILNHIMdXKMNLkKijLzSjRKKgtSNao0Nf//BwA), this is confusing the matter.

The line `for col1, col2, col4, col5, col7, col8 in zip:` is trying to find an iterator called `zip` with 6 subcomponents. Because `zip()` is a built-in, Python reads this line as "iterate through the `zip` type" but types are not iterable, so you receive the corresponding error.  Had you picked something which was not a built-in, you would get a `NameError`

Your example is a little unclear, but I believe you can fix it by using the `finally` block below ([proof of concept](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Pzk/x1DBViHaUMdIxziWC8g1AnFNdEx1zGK5chMz83Iyi0tAQmDJ0ty8YiCnKrNAA6RTRwGkQZMrLb9IASKrkJkHZRVbcSkAAcwIvcSCgtS8FA2IpCZXQVFmXokGTFbz/38A)):

```
finally:
    columns = zip(col1, col2, col4, col5, col7, col8)
    for column in columns: 
        mainlist.append(column)
```

Comment: I am sorry for the poorly expressed question, I am quite confused myself truth be told! Thank you so much for the answer, this cleared up my misunderstanding of what zip is used for. Have you also got any idea on how I add the entire row from the xlsx file to the list? In all the rows where cell value in column 4 minus cell value in column 1 is not equal to 0 I want the entire row to be added to the list. The way I am writing it now I found is not working (numbers = df.iloc[:, 4], df.iloc[:,1][df.iloc[:, 4] - df.iloc[:,1] != 0].tolist()). It is only giving me cell values of column 4 and 1.